# bottom in css bug, float left

Tags: css, css-float

I'm floating a div to the right inside of body, however when I resize the window and scroll down, the background doesn't fill the whole column...I have a screenshot in the link below and here is my code ->

```
body {
        font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
        background-color:#292929;
        color:#cccccc;
        margin:0;

    }
    #sidebar {
            width:300px;
            background-color:#111111;
            height:100%;
            bottom:0;
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZAAB.png

It looks fine however when the window expands below where the list ends...

Thanks!

Comment: Is that all the CSS? Could you include the relevant html too? If those items really are inside the sidebar div they must be positioned in a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the position of your DIV relative to the parent(body). ie: position:relative

Comment: @matt, Please accept the answer if this has helped resolve your problem. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
body {
        font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
        background-color:#292929;
        color:#cccccc;
        background-size: 100% 100%; /* Important*/
        margin:0;

    }
```

Good luck.